# How to upgrade contract so that solidity v0.5.0 can be used?

Tags: solidity

I tried to choose the v0.5.0 version of the solidity compiler recently, and found some errors when compiling the code. Can anyone tell me how to fix them? Thanks a lot!

1. transfer
   [image]
2. convert

   [image]

   [image]

----------------------update-----------------------

Alright, I found the answer in the docs of solidity. See below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the answer in the docs of solidity. See below:

[image]